# Does GraphQL has built in pagination?

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Does GraphQL offer built in pagination?
Like take first 10 items of collection, offest 2 etc?

I have read here: https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

On other sites I saw only those examples in which we had to implement these arguments by our own.

**Edit**: My question is not how to [GraphQL: How to implement pagination with graphQL-java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574964/graphql-how-to-implement-pagination-with-graphql-java) but question - is there built in option for that.

Comment: No, there is no pagination build in, you have to build yourself. Apollo Client has a section about pagination you can refer https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html. It can be offset based, cursor based and etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL: How to implement pagination with graphQL-java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574964/graphql-how-to-implement-pagination-with-graphql-java)

Comment: @xwlee thanks - so i need to implement it - thanks

Comment: How you paginate depends on the storage used. A built-in pagination would mean requiring a specific storage type, which would go against GraphQL's universal applicability and would generally be a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

Its not in build, you need to add input parameters into your api endpoint and then use them to implement pagination. ex- sequelize accepts these parameters as it is and generates query.

```
yourAPI(filters:yourInputFilters,limit:Int,offset:Int)
```

Sample with sequelize :

```
model.findAndCountAll({
            where: filters,
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset
})
```